# Trying to use Javascript to output to certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

After making the API request and getting back the JSON, I haven't been able to get the javascript to output to the targeted div labled #photolist, I just get a blank screen.

Here is my HTML JQuery Mobile

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>JQuery Mobile Web</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquerymobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">

<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquerymobile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b" data-title="Photo Grid">
 <div data-role="header">
   header
 </div><!-- header -->
 <article data-role="content">
    <img src="images/ART_Logo.png" width="100%">
    <h1>The Exclusive List</h1>
</article>

<section id="photos" data-theme="b">
<div data-role="content">
    <div class="ui-grid-c" id="photolist"></div>
</div><!--content-->
</section><!--Photos-->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-fullscreen="true">
<div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home" data-transition="slide" data-icon="home"    >Home</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div><!-- footer -->
</section><!--Home Page-->


<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=123910575@N04&format=json"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Script

```
function jsonFlickrFeed(data)
{
console.log(data);

var output = '';

for (var i = 0; i < data.items.lenght; i++)
{
    var title = data.items[i].title;
    var link = data.items[i].media.m.substring(0,56);
    var blocktype = 
        ((i % 4) === 3) ? 'd':
        ((i % 4) === 2) ? 'c':
        ((i % 4) === 1) ? 'd':
        'a';
    output += '<div class="ui-block-' + blocktype + '">';
    output += '<a href="#showphoto" data-transition="fade"         onclick="showPhoto(\'' + link + '\', \'' + title + '\')">';
    output += '<img src="' + link + '_q.jpg" alt="' + title + '">';
    output += '</a>';
    output += '</div>';
}
$('#photolist').html(output);
}

function showPhoto(link, title){
var output = '<a href="#photos" data-transition="fade">';
    output +='<img src="' + link +'_b.jpg" alt="' + title + '">';
    output +='</a>';
    $('#myphoto').html(output);
}
```

Comment: if possible add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Not to familiar with Jfiddle, would github work?

Comment: Please JSfiddle for sure on this, will be likely to receive a better response.

Comment: Github would work for me if the links (javascript) and ressources (images, etc) work after a download. But as others have stated codepen.io or jsfiddle.com or plnkr.co make it easier to collaborate.

Comment: it looks like your photos section is outside of the data-role=content article. jQM will not show the section because it is not included in the page content. Try moving the section inside the article.

Comment: Does this help? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xCJsd

Comment: And here is the Jfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/L2R7N/). @ezanker that got the data printing out to the console now, but still nothing displaying.

Comment: Here is your updated fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/L2R7N/1/ you misspelled length in your for loop.

Comment: @ezanker I see you manually added the data, I would like it to use the flickr API and grab the data that way.

Right now I just see 4 broken images links.

Comment: Your question implied you are not having problems with the api, just the showing of the data. My fiddle answers that question. Are you also having API issues?